# How to run a bash script on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

All my bash scripts don't seem to run on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  I created a dummy bash shell script (dummy.sh).  The script's permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x@
```

The script has these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
```

My $PATH is

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

However, every time I try to run dummy.sh in my terminal, I get this error:

```
-bash: dummy.sh: command not found
```

bash is confirmed to be in /bin

Can somebody help me to determine why I can't run shell scripts I create?

Comment: Is bash installed where you expect it to be? Do "ls -l /bin/bash", or just start bash up.

Comment: Yes, "ls -l /bin/bash" reveals its location.  I can also run bash by itself.

Comment: But in what directory does `dummy` exist?  That's the problem, no doubt.

Comment: Are you invoking your script as: ./dummy.sh ? Alternatively, you can add "." to your path.

Comment: dummy.sh exists in a directory that is not in my path.

Comment: stackoverflowuser2010: I have not tried ./dummy.sh.  Oh hey, that works!  I didn't realize that ./dummy.sh is different than dummy.sh

Comment: Yes, you either need to use a full path to the script or put it in a directory in your `PATH`.

Comment: Let me go add . to my .bash_profile file....ok, that works!  Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add . to your PATH -- it's not there by default for good reasons. Just use "./" when you want to run something from the current directory.

Comment: What is the risk?  I'm not an experienced user of the terminal, so why is '.' not in the PATH by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have '.' in your path, and are not calling it with an explicit path.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.  What do you mean by "you don't have not in your path"?

Comment: Your path does not include `:.:`, so the shell will not know to look for commands in the current working directory.  All the command with `./dummy.sh` instead.

Comment: It's NOT a good idea to put '.' in your path. I recommend creating a directory like ~/bin to hold your personal scripts, and put this directory in your path.

Comment: I strongly agree with Barmar's recommendation to add `$HOME/bin` to your PATH. I'm not quite so convinced about the 'no `.` in PATH`, but it depends in part on who else uses the machine you're on. In a hostile environment (a shared machine in a university setting, for example), I would not include `.` in my PATH. In a situation where the machine is used by you alone, or in some corporate settings where you can trust your coworkers, then `.` in PATH is OK. I work in situations where `.` is safe enough; it is a risk judgement I have made. Not everyone agrees; their risk judgement is different.

Comment: It's my own machine, so the risk is low.  But, I'll keep this in mind for the future, as I didn't know this was a risk.